# How to implement a LAN between two systems, without a modem?

Tags: windows-xp, lan

I have two systems, and I want to transfer data from one system to another while doing my project. I do not have an internet connection, and I do not have a modem. Is there any possibility of connecting the two systems without a modem and by using single RJ45 cable?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar iam using XP

Answer (score 7):

If the two devices are in the same place (i.e. you don't need to connect them over the internet) you wouldn't use a modem, you'd use a hub or switch - a home modem router would work, but that's just because they are normally also a switch, and I guess this is where the confusion lies.

---

#### Answer:

You can simply connect two devices together and they will create something of an ad hoc network.

Normally to connect devices directly you need a RJ45 crossover cable (which isn't the same as a normal RJ45 cable), but if both devices have Gigabit Ethernet ports then they should work using a standard cable (thanks to **afrazier** for the reminder).

You have not mentioned what you wish to connect, so I'm going to assume it's two Windows PCs. In which case Microsoft has a [handy article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Connect-two-computers-using-a-crossover-cable) for you.

The basics are:

1. Link the machines with your cable.
2. Go to Network / Network Places / etc (Windows version dependant).
3. Turn on network discovery (and possibly file sharing).
4. Wait.
5. Browse the shared folders of the other PC via the Network Places / etc screen.

Comment: is it possible to access the content of system only one and another one does not have access rights to that system . here one system is administrator and another is user

Comment: The access each machine will have to the other will be identical to the access they would have over a "standard" switch based network. You need to setup folder sharing and/or any other services you need in the usual manner. Each machine should present an IP address and you can reference that as usual in any required software (in fact, pinging the machines from one-another is a useful test).

Comment: A crossover cable isn't required if both systems have GigE ports -- auto-MDIX is part of the GigE standard.

Comment: @afrazier, thanks for that. I knew there was a reason it sometimes isn't needed, but couldn't for the life of me remember what it was. I'll remove the vaugeness from my answer.

Comment: please give me clarity between two of them

Comment: @King Sorry, between two of what?

Comment: please give me the clarity which one is correct answer then only i am ready to implement it

Comment: @King - Do you mean if you need a crossover cable? That depends on the two computers you are connecting. If they both have Gigabit ethernet cards then you can use a standard RJ45 cable. If one or both of them does not, then you might need a crossover cable.